# Is entry in colum a (at least once) related to entry in colum b?

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I'm stuck with a seemingly simple spreadsheet (LibreOffice) problem. Assuming I have three columns given as Name, Day and Mood; how can I find out if person x was happy at least once?

[image]

In a second sheet I have the names in column 1. In column 2 I would like an answer if "happy" was met at least once. Ideally like such:

[image]

It is not important that the actual mood is displayed, a yes/no answer for a given mood would be enough. I tried it with

> =VLOOKUP(A2,Data.$A$1:$C$7,3) (in field B2 of the answer sheet)

but without result. I see where the limitation lies with the formula but I cannot find another approach.

The file can be seen here if necessary:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5vU4bWlwahrdUV5d01hVXV6UTA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Put this in cell B2 on your second sheet:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!A2:A7,A2,Data!C2:C7,"happy")
```

It will first check for the name listed to the left (A2--Eric), then will check for those, which ones in column C also match "happy".

If you're looking to get just an acknowledgement of "Yes"/"No", you can change it to:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Data!A2:A7,A2,Data!C2:C7,"happy")>0,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thank you. Cannot get this to work though because the function COUNTIFS doesn't seem to exist in my version of LibreOffice (3.5).

Comment: Sorry about that--didn't realize it didn't have countif(s). Here's an alternative.

    =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!A1:A7=A2))*SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet!B1:B7="happy"))>0,TRUE,FALSE)